# ASP MVC - Html.BeginForm from within an area for a controller without area

Tags: c#, html, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view that is created within a MVC area.
from this view i want to add an Html form that gets to an action on a controller that is not in any Area but just in my main controller folder.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <input type="submit" value="TEST" />
}
```

When i execute this code it tries to find my controller in the same area and fails, following html is generated

```
<form action="/MyApp/en/MyController/MyMethod" method="get">
```

this actually works on other calls:

```
http://localhost:18183/MyApp/nl/OtherController/OtherAction
```

My action on the controller without area can be reached in the browser like this:

```
http://localhost:18183/MyController/MyMethod
```

But when i add the form the classic way it still doesn't work:

```
<form action="/MyController/MyMethod" method="get">
```

How can i achieve to call this controller?

Comment: You should start your investigation from Global.asax file. Check function RegiterRoutes(...) and route table which was set up before an application was started.

Answer (score 11):

You need to specify an annonymous object to the routeValues attribute:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", new { area = "" }, FormMethod.Get))
{
}
```

If you wanted to go to a different area rather than no area, modify the empty quotes to be your new area

Documentation for this overload is available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492933(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: As an aside - this mechanism works for all HTML Helpers including Html.ActionLink etc which will also not move you outside of the existing area unless specified. Just make sure object parameter you pass it into is routeValues not htmlAttributes